# Data output are correct but row positions are changing in PL/SQL Developer

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I am running a big SQL query (which i ant able to show ) in PL/SQL Developer tool. Out put of data is correct in my local Data Base and UAT server Data Base. But the problem is that why row position of Local Database is differ from the UAT server Data Base .

Local DB Stricture:

```
          PID  Termination_Date   Hire_Date</b>
```

Row 1->    001      2013/07/01                2012/07/01
Row 2_.     001                                                  2014/01/01

UAT DB i:

Row1 -> 001                                      2014/07/01
row2 ->001             2013/07/01           2012/07/01

if we consider that the Local DB Row 1 is coming in the 2nd position in UAT DB.
Note:-
I am running same SQL query for same employee ID.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix it by adding ORDER BY clause in your query so result will be same no matter where you execute your query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but what should be the root caused of this issue.

Comment: not sure, but some DB client use default ORDER BY ASC or DESC, as mentioned at http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not an issue: it's a FEATURE.  If you don't explicitly ask for a specific row ordering by using "order by..." (and it is my understanding that you aren't doing it),  you are telling oracle : 
"look, oracle i don't really  care of the result order,  i just want you to retrieve these rows in the quickest way you are capable of" 
And this is exactly what it does. If you are getting a resut order you hoped for without having asked for it, you are just being very lucky. 
 To oversimplify it,  just imagine that oracle is able to retrieve data only by doing just full table scans: in this hypothetical case,  without an order by clause you would get the rows in the exact order they are physically stored in the database files. And you can't predict this order! you might think that this order coincides with the order the rows were inserted in the db,  but this is true only until a certain point: oracle might decide to insert a new row by recycling the space that once was occupied by a previous row that has been deleted. 
 This is just to give you a simple example,  but there are many other factors that can influence the casual result order:
Oracle decides the "execution plan"  of a query taking in consideration factors that may differ on each server: available memory is a factor,  actual data statistics are another. 
 A server may decide that the best execution plan is a full table scan,  another one could decide to use an index.

Moreover: the same query, even if you actually issue an "order by", is expected to give different results depending on the national settings of the CLIENT (not server) used by the person issuing the query: different countries have different rules about how to do alphabetical sorting : some say that numbers come before letters,  some say the opposite. 
 Other example: lets say you extract the numeric day of week (1..7) and you sort on it. Well: in most countries of Europe the first day of week is Monday,  not Sunday (Sunday is the last). 
 So: whenever you want a specific sort order,  you have to ask for it. And you must carefully ask yourself if the order by you want could be influenced by the national settings of the user executing the query: if you don't your application may crash if used by someone who is connecting with a French version of Windows (and it could be a new potential  customer from a country you didn’t expect your software to be sold. This culd make you loose the customer) .